# Как поместить блок рядом с nav?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй блок необходимо разместить в одну строку с nav.

*Может нужно как то поменять структуру html?*

P.s. решение **без** *js*, *bootstrap*'а и *position: absolute*

---

Код:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant:wght@300;400&family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;700&family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgb(42, 61, 59);
  /* font-family: 'Cormorant', serif;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; */
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1110px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 680px;
}

.logo {
  height: 75px;
}

.nav__item {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav__search {
  padding-left: 28px;
  background-image: url('../assets/header/search.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.info__title {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #43FFD2;
  text-align: end;
}

.info__text {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav">
      <a class="logo" href="#"><img src="" alt="Логотип"></a>
      <a class="nav__item" href="#">Каталог</a>
      <a class="nav__item" href="#">Доставка и оплата</a>
      <a class="nav__item" href="#">Контакты</a>
      <a class="nav__item" href="#">FAQ</a>
      <a class="nav__item nav__search" href="#">Поиск</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="info__mail">
        <p class="info__title">zakaz@loverflower.by</p>
        <p class="info__text">Доставка 24/7 по договоренности с оператором</p>
      </div>
      <div class="info__street">
        <p class="info__title">ул. Тимирязева 67</p>
        <p class="info__text">10:00 до 21:00 без выходных</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При текущей раскладке элементов можно добавить эти два свойства в уже имеющиеся стили

```
.container {
  /* ... */
  display: flex;
}

.info {
  /* ... */
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```